# Java JTextPane italics help

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

So I am working on a Java GUI application where there is text styled with italics in a JTextPane which the user can copy. What I need is the user to be able to copy and paste the text into a Microsoft Word document without losing the italic styling. At the moment it all changes to plain text when pasted. How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696046/how-to-copy-styled-text-in-jtextpane

Comment: No that seems to be more about making a text editor. I need to know if it is posible to copy the text straight from a textpane or simular command into word without losing the styling.

Answer (score 2):

Set proper EditorKit e.g. RTFEditorKit or HTMLEditorKit.